# Displaying Database through for-each loop

Tags: java, php, html, sql

I am trying to display a database using a for-each loop, however each of my get methods are highlighted and display that they cannot be found in my other class. I am very new to PHP and have no idea why this error is occurring.

For-Each Loop:

```
    <?php foreach ($view->productDataSet as $productData) {
             echo '<td>'.$productData->getProductID().
            '</td><td>'.$productData->getProductName().
            '</td><td>'.$productData->getProductPrice().
            '</td><td>'.$productData->getProductDesc().
            '</td><td>'.$productData->getProductManufacturer().
            '</td><td>'.$productData->getQuantity().
            '</td><td>'.'<img src="images/'.$productData->getPhotoName().'"   alt="no picture"/>'.
             '</td> </td>';
     } ?>
     </tbody>
```

I believe the problem is occurring in the line `$view->productDataSet as $productData` however I don't really know what this line of code means. The class below is my productDataSet class which calls the sql query that should display the table.

```
class ProductsDataSet {
protected $_dbHandle, $_dbInstance;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_dbInstance = Database::getInstance();
    $this->_dbHandle = $this->_dbInstance->getdbConnection();
}

public function fetchAllProducts() {
    $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM products';

    echo $sqlQuery;

    $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); // prepare a PDO statement
    $statement->execute(); // execute the PDO statement

    $dataSet = [];
    while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $dataSet[] = new ProductData($row);
    }
    return $dataSet;
}
```

Sorry if this is isn't set out well. Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't add urgent begging to your questions anywhere on the web - not appropriate when addressing volunteers `:-)`.

Comment: Sorry just have been struggling. Are you unable to help?

Comment: Many reviewers will look through questions from new users in order to ensure quality on Stack Overflow. We might not be experts on your specific problem, but we are well rounded enough to have good input either way. The best way to get a quick response is to make your question as specific as possible while keeping it as brief as possible. Making it to where the only thing read by the volunteer is exactly the information they need to spit out an answer. Anything more will repulse many less knowledgable people with the answer away. Anything less will detriment from the quality of your answer.